# Authorize as Roles = "Admin" during login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

First of all i am new to MVC user authentication system. Code bellow is working fine for authenticate normal users but i wanted to log all user as per under MVC role based system. So admin user can only see admin controller and normal user cant see admin controller. I already made it on my admin controller i have added "[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]" and i am also redirecting correctly to specific controller during login filter inside login controller. Now my issue is: How can i tell MVC "[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]" is only accessed who has admin role? I mean how can i assign a user as admin from my login controller bellow? Ask any question if may have

Administrator Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Blexz.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class AdministratorController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Administrator
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Login Controller:

```
//Login post
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(UserLogin login, string ReturnUrl="")
        {
            string Message = "";
            using (BlexzWebDbEntities db = new BlexzWebDbEntities())
            {
                var v = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == login.Email && x.IsEmailVerified == true).FirstOrDefault();
                int RoleId = db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == login.Email).Select(x => x.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();
                string RoleTypeName = db.Roles.Where(x => x.RoleId == RoleId).Select(x => x.RoleType).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    if (string.Compare(Crypto.Hash(login.Password), v.PasswordHash) == 0)
                    {
                        int timeOut = login.RememberMe ? 43800 : 100; // 43800 == 1 month
                        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(login.Email, login.RememberMe, timeOut);
                        string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                        var cookie = new System.Web.HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
                        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeOut);
                        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);


                        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
                        {
                            return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                        }
                        else if (RoleTypeName == "Admin")
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Administrator");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("User", "Home");
                        }


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Message = "Invalid Credential Provided";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Message = "Invalid Credential Provided";
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Message = Message;
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove FirstOrDefault  from RoleTypeName selection and change it as

```
string[] RoleTypeName = db.Roles.Where(x => x.RoleId == RoleId).Select(x => x.RoleType);
```

and change the checking as

```
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl))
{
  return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
}
else if (RoleTypeName.Contains("Admin"))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Administrator");
}
else
{
    return RedirectToAction("User", "Home");
}
```

Change your ticket as shown below

```
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        version: 1,
        name: UserName,
        issueDate: DateTime.Now,
        expiration: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(httpContext.Session.Timeout),
        isPersistent: false,
        userData: String.Join(",", RoleTypeName));
```

and After that in global.asax you would do something like this:

```
public override void Init()
{
    base.AuthenticateRequest += OnAuthenticateRequest;
}

private void OnAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        var decodedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
        var roles = decodedTicket.UserData.Split(new[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, roles);
    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
}
```

}

Comment: what you mean by global.aspx?

Comment: Not aspx it asax, In MVC application solution it is an optional application file that contains code for responding to application-level events raised by ASP.NET or by HttpModules. It handles application events like Application start, Session, Authentication